# shared value between 2 js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I declared a variable with inline method in let say index.php, like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = 1;
</script>
```

and how can I use it in the external js file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your index.php file, you could have:

```
<!-- index.php -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = 1;
</script>
```

And the JS file:

```
// main.js
function stuff() {
    var theValue = a || 1;
}
```

Instead of the js file being dependent on the variable, perhaps you want the variable dependent on the js file:

```
<!-- index.php -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = 1;
someFunctionInMain(a);
</script>
```

And then in the js file:

```
// main.js
function someFunctionInMain(theVariable) {
    console.log(theVariable);
}
```

This is all very dependent on *scope*, but if you're working in global/window scope, this should all work just fine. If not you need to reference the variables/functions appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the external script file comes **after** your script above, it can just use `a`. If you want to be extra safe, try initialising it with a default value, eg

```
// external_script.js
var a = a || 1; // or some other sane default
```

Comment: the || means `or` ? this is my first time seeing this kind of syntax

Comment: @user3033162 Yes, it's *Logical OR*. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Comment: what is that for? a || 1?, a = 1 or 1, I'm confused

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use Local storage feature
You can refer to this answer for more details
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13586683/848841

Comment: Would you care to elaborate on why local storage would be best for this, in what scenario(s), and what is the benefit? I'm curious myself.