# Get and Set javascript value in localStorage

Tags: javascript, php, local-storage

Hai I want to get javascript value using LocalStorage and stored a value in php. I don't know how to set a value so kindly provide me the solution.

```
var getdate1 = document.getElementById("eventDayName").innerHTML = selectedDate.toLocaleString("en-US", {
            month: "long",
            day: "numeric",
            year: "numeric"
        }); 


        localStorage.getItem('getdate1', val);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loading JS LocalStorage into PHP Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923813/loading-js-localstorage-into-php-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For set a value in localStorage use `window.localStorage.setItem` like

```
window.localStorage.setItem('getdate1', JSON.stringify(getdate1));
```

```js
var getdate1 =document.getElementById("eventDayName").innerHTML = selectedDate.toLocaleString("en-US", {
            month: "long",
            day: "numeric",
            year: "numeric"
        }); 
window.localStorage.setItem('getdate1', JSON.stringify(getdate1));
```

Comment: The value will be set                                              
 localStorage.setItem("getdate1", getdate1);
//get
              var getval =  localStorage.getItem("getdate1");

Comment: How can i set this value to php inside value <input type='text' id='inputid' value="" name='myDate' >

Comment: @sixthstar <input type"text" id="inputid" value = "<?php echo (isset($myDate))?$myDate:'';?>" name='myDate' >

Comment: @sixthstar set javascript or PHP valuse

Comment: Great Sir. That's Working fine..Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code:

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");

//get
localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

Comment: I want to set a variable and assign to php value thats main logic. (e.g) <input type="hidden" value="{//localstorage variable}"

Comment: what does it mean here by php value

Comment: you can bind it with input by id of input

Comment: var x = localStorage.getItem("lastname");

Comment: $('#inputid').val(x);

Comment: when i alert the above value it show "object object" and How can i set this value to php inside value <input type='text' id='inputid' value="" name='myDate' >

Comment: then use localStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(object_to_set));

Comment: localstorage set and get item works but this will not workk as follows: $('#inputid').val(getval);