# How read a Object into localstorage javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, local-storage

now i save an array in my localStorage, and works fine but how get atribute by attribute. How write the cicle for?

localStorage.setItem('bultosStorage')

```
[{IdBulto: 9407981, EstadoEntrega: "A", Bulto: "025602", Contenedor: "025602"}]
0: {IdBulto: 9407981, EstadoEntrega: "A", Bulto: "025602", Contenedor: "025602"}
1: {IdBulto: 9407980, EstadoEntrega: "A", Bulto: "025604", Contenedor: "025603"

alocalStorage = localStorage.getItem('bultosStorage');
```

How i get IdBulto, Bulto, Contenedor, and before add a new node a JSON.

I have json :

"ControlEntrega": 107252,
"IdEstadoDespacho": 1,
"IdEstadoRetirado": 2,
"IdEstadoCobro": 2,
"IdEstadoEntregaFallidas": 0,
"IdEstadoGaveta": 2,
"CodigoLocalidad": 1,
"UsuarioActualizacion": "Paul.Rizzo",
"IpActualizacion": "LiquidacionEntrega",
"Proceso": "E",
"Detalles": [
{
"ControlEntregaDetalle": 3774286,
"ControlEntrega": 107252,
bultosEntrega": [
{
"idBulto": 9407982,
"contenedor": "010168",
"bulto": "010168",
"estado": "A"
}
]
}
]

Bultos Entrega most add whith the data for.
Thanks

Comment: parse local storage object? iterate thru as you would a normal a object

Comment: var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('testObject');

console.log('retrievedObject: ', JSON.parse(retrievedObject));

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get and Set javascript value in localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59169345/get-and-set-javascript-value-in-localstorage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing the array as a string, and so you can parse it to JSON when you get it back from the local storage

```js
var arr = [{ IdBulto: 9407981, EstadoEntrega: "A", Bulto: "025602", Contenedor: "025602" },
{ IdBulto: 9407981, EstadoEntrega: "A", Bulto: "025602", Contenedor: "025602" },
{ IdBulto: 9407980, EstadoEntrega: "A", Bulto: "025604", Contenedor: "025603" }]

// Store your array
localStorage.setItem('bultosStorage', JSON.stringify(arr));

// Retrieve your array
var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bultosStorage'));

// Access your array elements
for (let element of obj) {
    console.log(element.IdBulto, element.Contenedor, element.Bulto, element.EstadoEntrega)
}
```

Comment: [This has already been asked.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59169345/get-and-set-javascript-value-in-localstorage) please consider flagging instead?

Answer (score -1):

```js
alocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bultosStorage'));
```

when you set object in localstorage use:

```js
localStorage.setItem('object', JSON.stringify(object))
```

Comment: Check the edit.