# Passing data from localstorage (javascript) to php

Tags: javascript, php, local-storage

So i have data in my local storage and i want to use this data for php.
Is it possible to include the data from the local storage it in my php code?
I know it can work with cookies but is there another possibility? thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loading JS LocalStorage into PHP Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923813/loading-js-localstorage-into-php-variable)

Comment: no i already looked this up it sadly dosent help me

Comment: May I ask how it doesn't help you?

Comment: as i said in the question i search for a method to pass data from the local storage to my php code, the link that you send did not provide such a method

Comment: Please share your attempt at writing code to do this, or at least show your existing JS which works with localstorage, and PHP code where you want to use it.