# How to keep the current view after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php, html, listview, gridview

Hello I have made this js code to change the view from List to Grid and the opposite as well but I want to keep the current view state after refreshing the page, I have seen many videos talking about cookie and localStorage but I don't know how to use them since I am still beginner in programming could you tell me how to do ?

script.js:

```
let x = document.getElementById('x');

let z = document.getElementById('z');

 x.addEventListener('click', function() {

    let className = z.className;
    if (className == 'list') {
        z.className = 'grid';

    }else{
        z.className = 'list';
    }

});
```

index.php:

```
 <i class="" id="x"></i>
<div class="list" id="z">
          .
       centent
          .
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

- load the stored class from `localStorage`
- see whether it's valid and different from the current class
- store its current value upon each click

```
let x = document.getElementById('x');

let z = document.getElementById('z');

let cl = localStorage.getItem("class");

if (cl !== z.className) z.className = cl;

 x.addEventListener('click', function() {

    let className = z.className;
    if (className == 'list') {
        z.className = 'grid';

    }else{
        z.className = 'list';
    }
    localStorage.setItem("class", z.className);

});
```

Since stackoverflow.com considers direct operation with `localStorage` to be unsafe, I had to create a Fiddle for proof-of-concept. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/q68vnctL/

You can test by running it, clicking the "Click Me!" button as many times as you like, click on "Run" again and see that the color remains whatever it was.

Comment: I'm happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

localstorage is used as key-value pairs, both being always strings.

you can use `localStorage.setItem('view-setting', 'list')`.
this will create a localstorage variable named `view-setting` and will define its value as `list`. You can fetch the data using localStorage.getItem('view-setting'). Similarly items can be deleted using localStorage.removeItem('view-setting').

So after setting the view in localStorage, you can fetch it and on reload check its last stage and add conditionals in HTTP accordingly.

You can get further help from:
[Loading JS LocalStorage into PHP Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923813/loading-js-localstorage-into-php-variable)
or
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp