# Localstorage to PHP variable

Tags: php, ajax

I am sending and retrieving some data with this ajax call and saving result in localstorage like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "list.php", 
    data: {values: values}, 
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result){
    var dataToStore = JSON.stringify(result);
    localStorage.setItem('key', dataToStore);
    }  
});
```

Then I am retrieving it in a separate PHP document like this and trying to add it to a PHP variable. I think the problem occurs because when I console.log, it logs 10 times or so. And I can't echo it in PHP. How do I pass it correctly?

```
<script>
var localData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key'));

$.each(localData, function(key, value){
console.log("This is the data that is stored", localData)
$.ajax({
type: 'post',
        data: {localData}, 
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result){
        console.log(result)
        }  

        });
</script>

<?php
$user_id = isset($_POST['localData'])?$_POST['localData']:"";
$verdier = implode(", ", $user_id);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are causing an `asynchronous functionality` of ajax() real pain by calling it in a loop

Why dont you use `join()` to join items with `", "` in js like what you do in php

```
<script>
var localData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key')).join(", ");


$.ajax({
type: 'post',
        data: {localData}, 
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result){
        console.log(result)
        }  

        });
</script>

<?php
$user_id = isset($_POST['localData'])?$_POST['localData']:"";
$verdier =  $user_id;
?>
```

You Should also cast `user`_id as an (int)  if **user_id need to be  a single value and int**

```
$verdier = (int) $user_id;
```

Comment: @That gives me an error about the jquery script. "TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a"

Comment: @ØyvindHjartnes this error is unrelated tot his script, you dont have foreach loop here

Comment: just a side note: if it is an int (since it is an id) it would be a good idea to cast it as an `(int)`, since localStorage data can be easily manipulated by the client and, therefore, since such data can be used in future queries (or maybe not) this can be a little bit dangerous to allow the client to freely send data to the server.

Comment: @A.B: of course you can, no need to ask, it was just to point that out because that answer is already great :P

Comment: @A.B So I need to loop over the variable and add split? I tried it like this `var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key'));
var localData = data.join(", ");` Without the loop, cause I can't seem to make it work

Comment: var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key')); var localData = data.join(", "); will work, can you speciffy what is the problem now, echo user it in php see what you got

Comment: @A.B Yeah no errors, it now logs twice, with the POST loading between the two logs. `$user_id = isset($_POST['localData'])?$_POST['localData']:"";
echo $user_id;` echoes nothing, while `$verdier = (int) $user_id;
echo $verdier;`echoes 0. Post shows this in console `localData 
4, 10, 11, 13, 16, 17, 22, 24`which are the values I'm trying to add to the PHP variable

Comment: in $.ajax() try `data: { localData: localData }` and in php see output as  `$user_id = isset($_POST['localData'])?$_POST['localData']:""; echo $user_id;`

Comment: @A.B Doesn't seem to work. The data must be incompatible with a PHP array. I probably have to handle the js variables a different way

Comment: @ØyvindHjartnes you are missing somethig, i have been doing these things for years :)

Comment: @A.B Yeah, I'm checking everything :P

Comment: @A.B Is the problem perhaps that these are not strings?