# How to pass the values of localstorage from view to controller to use as php variable in another view

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In view on click of button am using location.href to pass on to controller. How can i pass the localstorage value in order to use it as a php variable

In view:

```
echo Html::button('Proceed', [  
    'onclick' => "
        var dataVal =  localStorage.getItem('Customers');
        if(dataVal.length > 0) {
            location.href = '" . Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['customers/orders']) . "';
        }else{
            alert('Please add some items to order!')
            return false;
        }",]);
```

Comment: php html js soup...This is going to be an absolute pig to maintain.

Comment: As far as sending client side data from a browser with a get request, your options are url parameters or cookies. The former is probably the best option

Comment: Please can you explain in details?

Answer (score 3):

While this is generally not recommended practice, it is possible to concatenate the value to the URL:

```
location.href = '" . Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['customers/orders']) . "?Customers=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(dataVal));
```

Now, your PHP side has a query parameter `Customers` encoded as JSON, so decode as such:

```
$Customers = json_decode($_GET['Customers']);
```

Comment: Is there any other way to access the localstorage  as php variable?

Comment: It entirely depends on what you are doing. PHP is a server-side language. It doesn't understand anything about JS, or the browser, and knows nothing about it. To pass values to the server, you have to explicitly make them available. One 'automatic' way, for example, is the use of cookies and/or sessions. These are built-in the HTTP protocol and are understood and transmitted by both sides. `localStorage` is a pure client thing, so it never goes over the wire without your explicit code to do so.