# Get localStorage value into php

Tags: javascript, php

I have a variable set in localStorage and I want to get it into php. When php is executed the value is already set in local storage, but how should I get into php?

I tried something like this:

```
  $myvar = "<script> localStorage.getItem('productinfo')['s3_url']</script>";
```

But this for some reasons gives a `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

How should I approach this? Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can not directly get a localStorage value in PHP, when script is executed, because localStorage is contained in user's browser, and PHP is running on server. However, you can send the value from localStorage to a server with GET or POST request.

Answer (score 5):

You can't get local storage values from the server. You should use cookies instead. Local storage is client-side only. Cookies are for both. You can get the value with Javascript and then send it to the server in a form or with ajax, or set a cookie with the value and use $_COOKIE to access it.