# Submit the array from JavaScript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

- First, I put the array in localStorage into the variable. 
  `var urls = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("urls"));`
- Now I need to transfer this array to a variable in php in the same page.
- The ways I tried;

1. `$urls = array();`
   `for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){`
   `array_push($urls, "<script>document.write(urls[$i]);</script>");`
   `}`
   Actually it kind of works. 
   `<?php echo $urls[$i];?>`
   Normally when I say print to the screen, the variable works the way I want. 
   But 
   `<a href="download.php?urls=<?php echo $urls[$i]; ?>" style="text-decoration: none">`
   When I say, the variable returns empty.
   Or, when I say `<img src = "<?php $urls [$i]; ?>` it also returns blank.
2. AJAX 
   I tried very hard with Ajax and could not reach the result I wanted. My code is working. The problem is: I'm returning the variable with JS, but I can't use the variable over and over in php. I want to keep the variable in php and use it in php on the same page.
3. COOKIES 
   It worked for me perfectly. It meets what I want. 
   But 
   Data overload happened and crashed.
   I do not intend to use it.

In short, I need to transfer an array in javascript to an array in PHP. I will use the array I transferred to PHP among php codes continuously.

Or isn't what I want is possible because php is a server-side language?

- NOTE: My knowledge of JavaScript or PHP is limited. The primary language I use is SWIFT. I have been working on this problem for a long time. Thank you for your support.

Comment: if the data is generated in JS, then AJAX is probably the best bet. Reusing data stored in variables on the same page in PHP is trivial so how you are using it is probably the problem. But to be honest there isn't enough information here to push you in the right direction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get localStorage value into php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834919/get-localstorage-value-into-php)

Comment: To allow JavaScript to send data to PHP, you must send a request to the server, where PHP has access to the data. Here is a simple way to post data to the server: [Dynamically create inputs in a form and submit it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/133997/3113485).

Comment: @NicoHaase Sorry, it has not been fully resolved.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript you can fetch.

```
  fetch("https://yourapi.api",
  {
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          url: [
            "https://otherurl1.url",
            "https://otherurl2.url",
            "https://otherurl3.url"
          ]
        })
  });
```

If `window.localStorage.getItem("urls")` is array you can put `url:JSON.stringify(window.localStorage.getItem("urls"))`
and In PHP you can get

```
  $content = trim(file_get_contents("php://input")); //this will catch POST from JavaScript
  $decoded = json_decode($content, true); //this will decode from JSON to PHP array
  foreach($decoded['url'] as $url){
    echo $url;
  }
```

`$decoded` will be your array as PHP array

in PHP you can also check if post was sent as JSON

```
if ($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"] === "application/json") {
    $content = trim(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $decoded = json_decode($content, true);
}
```

---

To see as function/method, JavaScript will look like this

```
let fetchApi = () => {
    fetch("https://yourapi.api",
      {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({
              url: window.localStorage.getItem("urls")
            })
      });
};
```

and PHP, you can use this everywhere

```
public static function get_data_from_js(){
    $contentType = isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) ? trim($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) : '';
    $decoded = [];
    if ($contentType === "application/json") {
        $content = trim(file_get_contents("php://input"));
        $decoded = json_decode($content, true);
    }else{
        //You can do here anything
    }
    return $decoded;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I'm getting the array from JS. No problem there. I get the error "Warning: invalid argument supplied for foreach ()" in PHP. I could not get the data in LocalStorage with PHP.

Comment: Hi there, please test posted data with print_r($decoded); before you put it into forach() to see what's inside posted array.

Comment: It means you are not posting data to php. Can you show me your url how you are posting it?