# how to increment the previous value by the new value in every refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to add the existing value with the new value when the webpage refresh.
 I have two files which are the html and php file.
The php file will show a random number between 10 and 100. while the html file perform a get jquery to get the data from the php script. Then after webpage refresh, the existing values must be incremented by the new value.
For example,

```
the first value on the webpage is 24.
after refreshing the page, the new value is 89 from the php script
the value on the webpage must be 113 (24+89).
```

I am going to show you the code below.

showtotal.php

```
<?php


$random = rand(10,100);
echo $random;
?>
```

showtotal.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
 updateFromServer();
    var intervalID = window.setInterval(updateFromServer, 500);

    function updateFromServer() {
        $.get({
            url: 'showtotal.php',
            dataType: 'text',
            success: totalAttacks
        });
    }

    function totalAttacks(val) {
        $('#result').html('Events Today' + val);
    }
</script>
<h1 id="result"></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

what my code is show different values in every refresh. How to increment the existing values by the new values? Please help me . thank you

Comment: Use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Comment: You need to store that variable either with localstorage or sessionstorage

Comment: You could also store it in the url

Comment: @Xufox, i thought php cant access localstorage . refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855337/php-localstorage

Comment: @Azhar You don’t need to save the value server-side; save it client-side.

Comment: If i want the values to be saved if i close the browser and open, I must use cookies??? In other words, i want the value to be permanent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your old value in a PHP session and make this calculation in the PHP side, like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['old_value']))
    $_SESSION['old_value'] = 0;
$random = $_SESSION['old_value'] + rand(10,100);
$_SESSION['old_value'] = $random;
echo $random;
?>
```

Comment: however, when i close the browser and open, the values start from 0. If i want to use permanent storage

Comment: in this case you are force to save value in the database, session will remove when you close browser. simple save and get $_SESSION['old_value'] from database

Comment: if i do not want to use database, any other storage that has the ability to be permanent

Comment: As this data is not an important can save latest status in a file and every-time read and write on that instead of using session

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies), [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) or [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store the lastest value. In the case of the cookie, you can get it through the PHP file, so in your Javascript file you just need to call the PHP file.

Comment: you can access cookies with JS, it's not easy or fun but it can be done.

Comment: I know, the point was that he can move all the logic to the PHP file :)

Comment: ever parse a cookie with JS by hand, lol, that's some fun times.

Comment: if i want to use permanent storage, meaning if the browser close and open, that value will remain there. which storage do i need to use?? It cant be session storage as it will be reset if the browser close and open

Comment: @Azhar cookies or localstorage are your options, I will choose localstorage since it is easier to retrieve the data you want

Comment: is it possible to perform coding localstorage in php

Comment: No, localstorage its only accessible from javascript.

Comment: Damn... I am using php script to show the data.  I use ajax get to access the data from the php script.

Comment: i think i choose cookies as cookies can be used in php

Comment: I apologize for the spamming you @Frankusky

Answer (score 0):

You can store previous value in a hidden field.

```
function totalAttacks(val) {
    var pre_val = parseInt($('#prev').val());
    var new_val = pre_val+parseInt(val);
    $('#result').html('Events Today' + new_val);
    $('#prev').val(new_val);
}
```

Also add this to yr html

```
<input type="hidden" id="prev" value="0">
```

Comment: I believe this wont work, after refreshing the browser will load your DOM value instead of retrieving the last value