# Sending a localstorage variable to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, local-storage

I want to pass a local storage variable to PHP when the page loads. Here is what I tried

**profile.php**

```
$(document).ready(function(){              
    var userMarkVar = localStorage.getItem("userMark");
    jQuery.post("marks.php", {userMark: userMarkVar}, function(data){
        alert("Do something with marks.php responses");
    }).fail(function(){
        alert("Error");
    });
});
```

**marks.php**

```
<?php    
     $userMark = $_POST['userMark'];
?>
```

And then to test it, I **echo $userMark** in profile PHP. However whilst I get the success "Do something with marks.php responses" alert, I do not get the $userMark value echoed on **profile.php**.

Any suggestions?

Comment: suggestion: do a `var_dump($_POST)` to see what you've got. If there's no value check your networktab to see what get's actually sent.

Comment: _"I echo $userMark in profile php"_: where? right next to the `alert()`??

Comment: @Jeff So i did a var_dump, and got "array(0) { }" as the result. And i have the above script in the <head> with the <?php echo $userMark ?> in the <body>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo` `$userMark` in `marks.php`

marks.php

```
<?php

 echo $userMark = $_POST['userMark'];
 echo $userMark;

?>
```

profile.php

and alert `data` in javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

        var userMarkVar = localStorage.getItem("userMark");

        jQuery.post("marks.php", {userMark: userMarkVar}, function(data){
          alert(data);
        }).fail(function(){
          alert("Error");
        });
```

});

Comment: Thanks, this works as I get an alert with the localstorage data. However, how can i confirm that this is being sent to the php file? As i'd like to later send the data in the php file to a mysql database

Comment: the `alert(data)` already is the data from php sent back. So that's your confirmation.

Comment: u will get all variable send by javascript in marks.php where u can process the data to insert to database and then alert for successful additiion

Comment: whatever u echo in marks.php it will show in the alert it is the response back to javascript ajax

Comment: Great thanks, just checked it with my database - it works! And yes ofc! @pradeep

Answer (score 1):

your marks.php should look like this:

```
<?php

 echo $userMark = $_POST['userMark'];
 echo $userMark;
?>
```

Then you can access userMark from data on your script

Answer (score 1):

I run your code and everythings worked well ,

if you want to get the datas you use

```
alert(data);
```

only

Answer (score 0):

This cannot work!
The script is on the client side and PHP is on the server side!
You have to load your data in a HTML form and post it to your PHP file. Then only you can get it with $_POST[...]!